# Find all equivalence relations on a set with three elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

The question is:
There are ﬁve different equivalence relations on the set $A = \{ a,b,c \}$. Describe them all.

Can you just state the names of them, so it will be guidance for me.

Comment: Do you know that equivalence relations on a set $A$ are in natural one-one correspondence with partitions of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \{ a, b, c \}$. Then the five equivalence relations on $A$ are the following:

$R_1 = \{ (a,a), (b,b), (c,c) \}$

$R_2 = \{ (a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (a,b), (b,a) \}$

$R_3 = \{ (a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (a,c), (c,a) \}$

$R_4 = \{ (a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (b,c), (c,b) \}$

$R_5 = \{ (a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (a,b), (b,a), (b,c), (c,b), (a,c), (c,a)\}$